# Make Imageview Differentiate singletap and Scroll

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement single tap and Scroll on the same Imageview, I successfully implemented single tap but now I have no idea how to implement scroll. I need to implement different actions on single tap and scroll, for singletap I want to start an activity I've done that and now on scroll, I need to call a method say "updateData". Please help me. Below is my Code

```
    public class GestureListener extends
                GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

            // event when double tap occurs
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                tapped = !tapped;

                if (tapped) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);

                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }




                } else {



                }

                return true;
            }
        }

  image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Why not try to implement pull-to-refresh instead of a custom scrolling gesture? You just need to wrap your ImageView in a SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: I just need to show the properties of the image when the user scrolls down, how would the user know to pull to see the properties?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to extends `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` then set this custom listener for your `ImageView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final GestureDetectorCompat gdt = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new CustomGestureListener());
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed() called with: " + "e = [" + e + "]");
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            // do some stuff maybe..
            // do other stuff

            updateData(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);

            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

    }

    private void updateData(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        Log.d(TAG, "updateData() called with: " + "e1 = [" + e1 + "], e2 = [" + e2 + "], distanceX = [" + distanceX + "], distanceY = [" + distanceY + "]");

    }

}
```

Comment: How to call that method in onScroll?